# Connecting +1s on a Google+ Business Page and a webpage

Tags: social-media, google-plus

We have a Google+ page, but on our homepage we have ~280 +1s:

Is there any way to connect those likes to the business page?  We have used the rel=publisher thing.  Or do we have to start fresh like we have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, according to [this Google blog post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/11/grow-your-audience-with-google.html) you can combine all your +1s from Google+, your site and search results.

> You can also link your site to your Google+ page so that all your +1s -- from your Page, your website, and search results -- will get tallied together and appear as a single total.
>   ...
>   You can link your site to your Page either using the Google+ badge or with a  piece of code. To set this up, visit our Google+ badge configuration tool.

I assume that's in your settings somewhere. It may not be there right now as they say they're introducing the badge in the coming days.

Comment: Can anyone clarify this? I've read that post and it now links to https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/config but it's very unclear what exactly using the button this generates does. Does this button links +1s "from your Page, your website, and search results" together, as I believe Tom Gullen was asking for? How does it now which G+ page, URL, etc. to link together?

Comment: ...especially as that button just creates a link to the URL of your G+ page, so doesn't appear to do anything like what you quoted says...