# Button to +1 both website and Google Plus page?

Tags: google-plus-one, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connecting +1s on a Google+ Business Page and a webpage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21768/connecting-1s-on-a-google-business-page-and-a-webpage)

People can +1 both our website (ie. +1ing the URL of its home page) and our Google Plus business page. It would be desirable to link these +1s, so that +1ing our website added to the number of +1s for our Google Plus page, and vice versa. Is this possible? Is there any way to add a button to our website (possibly using some hand-written javascript) which +1s both?

## Related questions

A similar question's been asked at [Connecting +1s on a Google+ Business Page and a webpage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21768/connecting-1s-on-a-google-business-page-and-a-webpage) and I see others - like https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30075/google-plus-button-versus-pages-pluses - are being closed as 'exact duplicates' of this. However please note that the accepted answer to the former question appears to be incorrect, as I point out in my comments on it. Hence why I'm creating this new question to give this issue a chance of achieving an appropriate answer.

Comment: They are duplicates. If you feel that the answer to the original question is wrong, then you should down-vote it and [start a bounty](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) on it. Creating another question is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: OK, thanks for letting me know. Alas I don't have the rep to downvote the question or other much bounty but I guess I'll just hope someone notices the question hasn't been correctly answered...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can create a bounty, though. Even if it's a small one (50), it will still get a lot of attention.

Comment: OK, have done! I'll get the rep back soon hopefully :)